# vs10 c# function run after click

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make function work :

> int a = Convert.ToInt32(tb[0].Text);

After i click :

> button1

How to update textbox value after button 1 click?

```
//My Code  
    private void somefunction(){
    TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[2];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
    tb[i] = new TextBox();
    tb[i].Name = "textBox" + i;
    tb[i].Location = new Point(50 * i, 10);
    tb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 15);
    this.Controls.Add(tb[i]);     
    }

    //this code is static, how to make it update on click?
    int a, b;           
    a = Convert.ToInt32(tb[0].Text);
    b = Convert.ToInt32(tb[1].Text);
    }
// click event
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: That is so wrong, this localized thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    TextBox[] tb;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb = new TextBox[2];
        //...
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(tb[0].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is static example. If I would like to add some dynamic event handler , i would write this : 
button1.click += eventHandlerType(Method_name);